# How do I install Mac for Linux Theme? - Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: themes, mac

I've been looking for a Mac OS theme for Ubuntu for quite some time.

I came across MacBuntu, but I'd like to have something better.
Then I discovered Mac for Linux: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac4lin/?source=typ_redirect.

I downloaded it and extracted the files. 
It's written in the project's documentation - https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac4lin/files/OldFiles/Mac4Lin_Documentation.pdf/download - that I need to apply the GTK Metacity theme first - but I cannot find the proper window for changing a theme, despite having the Unity Tweak Tool. I cannot possibly start the process of changing the theme.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-5-steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 16.04, I put themes in Home > .themes

.themes is a hidden folder. You will have to use CTRL + H to view .themes and other hidden folders.

If you try CTRL + H and still do not find your .themes folder, you may need to create one.

Another location for themes is usr > share > themes

I somehow prefer .themes in Home folder for my custom themes though.

Get your Mac looking theme from the link below (it has many options )

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1167049/

Comment: I tried Ctrl + H and it  didn't work. I tried to create a folder for themes, but a message popped-up saying that there's such a folder already...

Comment: Found the .themes Folder. What should I do next?

Comment: For the themes I have, like Adapta, Numix etc, all you have to do is extract them and place it in .themes folders ( as a folder ). Then, go to Unity Tweak Tool and use it to select your theme.

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason

Comment: What happens when you select the entry in Unity Tweak Tool ?

Comment: You can install Cairo Dock from Ubuntu Software center if you just needs a Dock as in Mac. Go to Gnome-look.org and get a Mac themes, put it on .themes folder. I have updated my reply with a link for a Mac theme.